# Images and Kernels of tensor products of homomorphisms of modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras, tensor

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hopf algebra and let $M_1,M_2,N_1,N_2$ modules over $\mathcal{H}$. If $f:M_1\rightarrow N_1$ and $g:M_2\rightarrow N_2$ are homomorphisms of modules, then are the following equalities 
$Im(f\otimes g)=Im(f)\otimes Im(g)$ and $Ker(f\otimes g)=(Ker(f)\otimes M_2)+ (M_1\otimes Ker(g))$ true? Otherwise, what are the formulas for $Im(f\otimes g)$ and $Ker(f\otimes g)$?

Comment: In the general case, for the kernel formula you need some extra assumptions: Either flatness of $M_1$, $M_2$ or the $f$, $g$ being surjective.

Comment: By the way: do you consider the hopf algebra over a vector space? or the general case of an $R$-hopf algebra?

Comment: Yes, for my purposes, it suffices to consider Hopf algebras over a field, while the modules can be finite-dimensional.